# Error: "Controller" not found. You need to call "Get.put(Controller())" or Get.lazyPut(()=>Controller())"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have next code.

```
main() {
  Get.put(NavigationBarController());
  Get.put(JobListController());
  //...
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I do not use `bindings` because I do not use GetX routes/pages and use custom tabs-switching.

My widget is next:

```
class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  var jobCtrl = Get.find<JobListController>();
  
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      child: Column(children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => jobCtrl.startNewConfigToJob(), child: Text("Run")),
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Error: "JobListController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(JobListController())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>JobListController())"
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:56854/dart_sdk.js:5374:11)
```

Why I am getting this error? The Navigation bar Controller is also use Get.find and works fine:

```
class NavigationBarController extends GetxController {

  get to => Get.find<NavigationBarController>();

  var tabIndex = 0.obs;

  List<Widget> pages = [
      Dashboard(),
      TableStatisticSpeedView()
  ];

 Widget get currentPage => pages[tabIndex.value];

  void changeTabIndex(int index) {
    tabIndex.value = index;
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Here is full source code: https://github.com/bubnenkoff/monitor_client/blob/main/lib/main.dart#L28

Comment: Are you restarting the app after adding `Get.put` to your `main` function? You can't just hot reload.

Comment: @Lee3 Yes, I did full restart

Comment: it worked for me thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a separate file for dependency injection into that file put your dependencies.

```
Future<void> init() async {
Get.put(NavigationBarController());
  Get.put(JobListController());
}
```

call the init function from main and put  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() at the top of main function.

```
main() async{
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await di.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now at the widget class call the controller.

```
class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  var jobCtrl = Get.find<JobListController>();
  
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      child: Column(children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => jobCtrl.startNewConfigToJob(), child: Text("Run")),
```

Comment: But what difference to putting all in `init` instead of my approach with putting all in `main`? Why in my approach working `Get.put(NavigationBarController());` but `Get.put(JobListController());` get an error that it's did not found?

Comment: And why `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` is needed here?

Comment: Egh... I did as you wrote but got same error. Also `di.init()` is not found.

Comment: you need to import the file which has the init() method and after import you can name it as di
Example: 
import 'package:/........./dependency_container.dart" as di

Comment: I have imported file which has init method and named as di...even  i'm getting error..
```flutter:
The function 'init' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'init', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'init'.
```